# How to apply my uncommit local changes in svn to git, because our svn central repository just migrate to Git

Tags: git, svn

I am working on my project named BackOffice, I checkout it to my local from our central svn repository. I made some changes but not commit yet. Meantime, our team migrate this project from SVN to Git.

Obviously, I need to clone this project from out Git central repository and find a way to apply my changes to it.

I could make it by using a tool like Beyond Compare, compare my "svn edition" with my "git edition", find out all the changes I made and "copy" them to my "git edition".

Is there a better way?

Comment: Please add some more context and describe your situation in more detail. What do you mean by "rewind changes"? What do you have at present locally?

Answer (score 0):

Use [svn diff](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html) to capture the changes you have made compared to the revision you checked out. Save this diff to a file.

You should then be able to clone your git repository, and then apply the changes using [git apply](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply).